# How to add calculated values to a String when the method is static

Tags: java, string

```
public static String zoekAlleOplossingen(int a,int b,int c,int d,int begingrens,int eindgrens)
{
    for(int x=begingrens;x<=eindgrens;x++)
        for(int y =begingrens;x<=eindgrens;y++)
            for(int z = begingrens;z<=eindgrens;z++)
                if(a*x + b*y + c*z == d){

                    System.out.printf("%d*%d + %d*%d + %d*%d = %d%n",a,x,b,y,c,z,d);
                    oplossingen = "" + String.format("%d*%d + %d*%d + %d*%d = %d%n",a,x,b,y,c,z,d);
                }
    return oplossingen;


}
```

I cant find a way to add parts of the String that i calculated in the forlus to the variable oplossingen. I think that it's because my method is static but in my excercise i need to use this method as static. 
To sum it up, my question is:
How do i add parts of a String that i calculated to a variable in a method that is final?

Comment: Where did you declare the variable?

Comment: could you show a `zoekAlleOplossingen` function call?

Answer (score 0):

Static or not static: apparently you compute a string in several instalments, and you return that string. There is nothing "final" in your method.

I think that using a StringBuilder would be the best option.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

...
 sb.append( String.format("%d*%d + %d*%d + %d*%d = %d%n",a,x,b,y,c,z,d ) );
...

return sb.toString();
```

Adding to a String is done according to

```
String s = "";
...
  s += String.format(...);
```

but this is less efficient. Here, the String variable must not be final.

If the static method `zoekAlleOplossingen` should accumulate all calculated solutions from all invocations of that static method you need a static variable within the encompassing class. That could be a String or StringBuilder, according to the patterns shown here. But in this case making `zoekAlleOplossingen` return the result of a single invocation is, perhaps, superfluous.